# SmartGwt SelectItem how to select all values in the picklist in a single click

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

i need some help regarding SelectItem .my requirement is to  select all items in the picklist in selectitem in a singleclick.i used  selectItem.setMultiple(true);  selectItem.setMultipleAppearance(MultipleAppearance.PICKLIST); .checkboxes are coming for each available field in the picklist.i want to insert ALL keyword into my picklist at runtime.i am fetching values of picklist from database mysql. i tried SelectOtherItem but it is also not supporting.please help.....  with regards subodh

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add extra picker icon in select item to set all available values. Something like

```
PickerIcon clearPicker = new PickerIcon(PickerIcon.CLEAR, new FormItemClickHandler() {  
    public void onFormItemClick(FormItemIconClickEvent event) {  
        selectItem.setValues(values);
    }  
});
selectItem.setIcons(pickerIcon);
```

where values are all the values of Your picklist. You shoud also set PickerIcon image.